# Want to switch on calendar date doing some calculation

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am getting the time in seconds from a function and I have to move further it into days and from the date 2/11/1970 00:00:00 till time in seconds I am getting will be covered. Please help me how to achieve this, or help me to do calculation on dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I quite get your question, but if I do, have you tried the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object?

Here's an example of how you could get the day out of the time in milliseconds:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = new Date();
cal.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
int dayOfYear = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) date time API. IT should cater for your needs. [This](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html) should point you in the right direction.